# Showing a sequence of estimators is consistent

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, random-variables, variance, binomial-distribution

Let $X = (X_1, ... X_n)$ consist of $n \ iid$ Binomial rvs $X_i, s.t. X_i\sim \operatorname{Bin}(m, \theta), m \in \mathbb{N}, $ unknown $ \theta \in (0,1)$

Show that if $\hat\theta(X) := \frac{1}{nm+m}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$
, then $(\hat\theta_n(X))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a consistent sequence of estimators.

I know that if we find the bias and variance, then if

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{bias}(\hat\theta_n(X), \theta) \rightarrow 0$ and $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \operatorname{Var}_\theta(\hat\theta_n(X)) \rightarrow 0$, then we have a consistent sequence of estimators.

Hence, I have attempted to calcuate these:

(Updated answer, using variance answer from below, advice for bias):

Variance:
$\operatorname{Var}_\theta(\frac{1}{nm+m}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i) = \frac{1}{(nm+m)^2}\operatorname{Var}_\theta(\sum_{i=1}^nX_i)$

$=\frac{1}{n^2m^2 + 2nm^2 + m^2}\sum_{i=1}^n \operatorname{Var}_\theta(X_i)$

$=\frac{1}{n^2m^2 + 2nm^2 + m^2} n \operatorname{Var}(X_1)$ - since we have iid rvs

$=\frac{n}{n^2m^2 + 2nm^2 + m^2} m\theta(1-\theta)$

$=\frac{nm\theta(1-\theta)}{n^2m^2 + 2nm^2 + m^2}$

$=\frac{n\theta(1-\theta)}{n^2m + 2nm + m}$

So, $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{n\theta(1-\theta)}{n^2m + 2nm + m})$ = $lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}}{m+\frac{2m}{n}+\frac{m}{n^2}}) = 0$

Then Bias:
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}_\theta(\frac{1}{nm+m}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) - \theta
&=\frac{1}{nm+m}\mathbb{E}_\theta(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)-\theta\\
&=\frac{1}{nm+m}n\mathbb{E}(X_1) - \theta \mbox{ since we have iid rvs}\\
&=\frac{nm\theta}{nm+m}-\theta\\
&=\theta(\frac{nm}{nm+m}-1)\\
&=\theta(\frac{mn}{m(n+1)}-1)\\
&=\theta(\frac{n}{n+1}-1)\\
&=\frac{n\theta}{n+1} - \theta\\
&=\frac{n\theta-\theta}{n+1}
\end{align}
Then, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{n\theta-\theta}{n+1}) = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\frac{\theta}{n}-\frac{\theta}{n^2}}{\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2}}=0$

And hence we have a consistent sequence of estimators

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the variance, I divide $n^2$ in both the numerator and the denominator.
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \theta(1-\theta)}{n^2m+2nm+m} = \lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\frac{\theta(1-\theta)}{n}}{m+\frac{2m}{n}+\frac{m}{n^2}}=0
\end{align}

For the bias, many of your equal signs should be minus sign instead. The last few lines of your working doesn't make sense. But you should use a similar trick by dividing $n$ in both the numerator and denominator to get a conclusion.

Edit:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \theta}{n+1}-\theta=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{\theta}{1+\frac1n}-\theta=\theta - \theta = 0$$

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I have re-attempted the bias, I think I have now done this correctly?

Comment: Just divide by $n$, not $n^2$.